# How to create a readable date and time from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm using an api that returns the date as a string, like so:

> 2011-06-13T21:15:19Z

As you can imagine this is not the easiest format to understand. My goal is to get it to format like this:

> 9:15pm - 6/13/2011

Anyone know how to accomplish this? Do I need to use a regular expression or is there a way to convert this to a `DateTime`?

**NOTE:** I have tried to use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method but it didn't work. If this is the solution could you please show me how to convert the example above. Thanks.

Comment: What about DateTime.Parse, which is more forgiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string date = "2011-06-13T21:15:19Z";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

Comment: @loyalpenguin - Not a problem. Seems the answer was unanimous

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it with TryParse and it worked.  Using a try parse is better than parse because you can then handle for the cases the string didn't parse.  If your certain the string being passed is static, then I guess it isn't necessary.

```
        string Time = "2011-06-13T21:15:19Z";

        DateTime t;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(Time, out t)) 
        {
            //Works
        }
```

Comment: Definitely.  If the API is not 100% without a doubt guaranteed to return the datetime in that exact format, then TryParse supersedes Parse.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Parse` seems to work fine for that string:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2011-06-13T21:15:19Z");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("h:mmtt - M/d/yyyy"));
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get it the formatted string to look exactly how it is in your question, just throw a `ToLower()` on it:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("h:mmtt - M/d/yyyy").ToLower());
```

Also, all of the date and time string formatting options can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Parse is supposed to work with those ISO 8601 date strings.

Comment: and not only are they the easiest to understand, they sort naturally: date order = ASCII order! :^P

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.Parse.

```
void Main()
{
    var date = DateTime.Parse("2011-06-13T21:15:19Z");
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string you are looking for is `"hh:mmtt \- M/d/yyyy"`.